# Can I somehow override a parents style for a specific child?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, less

I'm working on an application with a main layout which has the bootstrap class "container-fluid".

```
<main class="container-fluid">
  [....]
//a child div where I'd like to remove the parent's padding for this div
   <div>
    [....]
   </div>
</main>
```

and as you probably know, container-fluid has padding in it, which is great, it's needed.

```
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
```

However, inside one of the child components, I'd like the padding to be removed.
I made a not-so-pretty image to display what I mean, I hope it helps:

[image]

I know I could just put the component outside of the main tag, however, I really need it to be inside for a specific reason, and that's why I'm wondering if I can somehow remove the padding of a parent div for a single child div.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nevermind, I suddenly figured it out :)

I put style="margin: -15px;" on the child div, and it worked wonderfully.